# How to store a Vapor Fluent model with decimal field

Tags: postgresql, vapor, vapor-fluent

I have a `Fluent` (`Postgres` backed) model that requires type `Decimal`, but I'm only allowed to store `.float`/`.double`.

```swift
// Model
final class Stat: Model, Content, Equatable {
    static let schema: String = "stats"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?
    
    @Field(key: "name")
    var name: String

    @Field(key: "earned_run_average")
    var era: Decimal // <-- CAN'T DO THIS
}
```

```swift
// Migration
struct CreateStatsTable: Migration {
    func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        return database.schema(Stats.schema)
            .id()
            .field("name", .string, .required)
            .field("earned_run_average", .decimal/*.decimal TYPE DOES NOT EXIST */, .required)
            .create()
    }

    func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        return database.schema(Stats.schema).delete()
    }
}
```

The above model with migration will fail. If this is not easily achievable (as easy as `.string` or `.double`) is there a way to get a behavior similar to type `Decimal` in `Fluent`?

Comment: As a work-around, try storing it as .int in the model, doing all your arithmetic using this data type and then create an extension to Int that reports it in the correct precision.

Comment: Use `Decimal` for your `era` model property and `.string` for `earned_run_average` in the migration.

Answer (score 2):

[Proper Decimal support for Postgres](https://github.com/vapor/postgres-nio/pull/194/) was added recently.

So you should be able to use `Decimal` in the `Model` for encoding/decoding to and from a `Decimal` value in the Postgres DB without any issues.

As for the `Migration`, there still isn't a `.decimal` `DataType` so you can simply use a custom field for the Postgres Database like `numeric` as so:

```
.field("earned_run_average", .sql(raw: "NUMERIC(7,2)"), .required)
```

This should allow you to use `Decimal` without any issues.